# awk read with max length instead of seperator

Tags: bash, awk, fixed-length-record

Is there anyway so that I can read strings from a file with fixed length in `awk`?

I have a file named `dictionary`, and another file named `indexes` and I want to read strings with fixed length of 4 from `indexes` and replace them with the first column of `dictionary`.

for example :

indexes file :

```
0201000800030307
```

dictionary file:

```
hello   hey
hi      hoy
baby    hoy
baba    boy
```

and i want the result to be this:

```
0201   hey
0008   hoy
0003   hoy
0307   boy
```

is it possible to do it using `awk`? or if it is not, is there anyway to do it in `bash`?

Edit: `indexes` file can contain any ascii charachter.

Comment: Is indexes just one long line ?

Comment: @Jidder Edit : actually indexes file can contain `0A`(\n) charachter too

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR {
        while ($0!="") {
            a[++i] = substr($0,1,4)
            $0 = substr($0,5)
        }
        next
    }
    { print a[FNR], $2 }
' RS='^$' idx RS='\n' dict
0201 hey
0008 hoy
0003 hoy
0307 boy
```

Comment: I got the exact same solution :(

Comment: Well, not EXACT same... :-) See my comments under your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
awk 'FNR==NR{while($0){a[++x]=substr($0,1,4);$0=substr($0,5)}next}$1=a[FNR]' file file2
```

Comment: it will fail if 4 consecutive characters in the index file are zeros or blanks. It also will fail if there are `\n`s in the index file as the OP says there can be. Other than that it looks stunningly familiar ;-).